# node.js s3 file browser/explorer

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, file-browser, pydio

I've been searching the web for a node.js package that mimics to some extent [CKFinder](http://cksource.com/ckfinder) or [AjaXplorer](http://pyd.io/). I am in need of browsing S3 but even if the package was dedicated to local storage that would be a great starting point. The main purpose of the package would just need to select a file to obtain the link in connection with CKEditor. Does anyone know of a package that implements something like this?

Comment: For those interested I ended up creating my own plugin and it wasn't too hard. Essentially, I created a UI for listing and doing some simple things with an s3 bucket. From there you just have to hook it up to the CkEditor image toolbar. However, I can't post it as an answer because it's not a standalone package. Something `node.js` still needs.